# I need python library which support graphic objects manipulation

Tags: python, wxpython

Does exists library for Python which gives me advantages for 2D graphic objects manipulation with mouse events. SVG + Javascript works beautiful for web app, but I need to build desktop application which allows user to drag vector objects and to have events like "onmouseover", "onmousedown"...

It doesn't have to be based on SVG, but to allow similar kind of manipulation as SVG+Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [PyQT](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) (Python wrappers for Qt). The QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView classes do just this.

An example here: http://lateral.netmanagers.com.ar/stories/BBS53.html.

I've used them on several occasions, and they have good performance, are very flexible and are easy to use.

Comment: At first glance it seems to be awesome classes, but the fancy animation is the last thing I need. Is it capable for mouse interaction with shapes as well?

Comment: @Alex: It is great for mouse interaction with shapes. And also collision detection between shapes if you need it. The fancy animation is entirely optional.

Answer (score 1):

Pycairo bindings for Cairo is another alternative http://cairographics.org/pycairo/